# How to store the ArrayList in matrix format and ArrayList Should be String data?

Tags: java, arrays, jakarta-ee

In this code I Got Error `ArrayoutofBoundException` and `NullPointerException` in the `ml.getV()` method

This is my matrix class

```
public class Matrix {
    private double [][] V = null;
// public members
    public static int RowsOfVMatrix = 9219;
    public static int ColsOfVMatrix = 5;
    public static int ROW_INCREASE = 20;

    public double[][] getV() {
        return V;
    }
    public void setV(double[][] v) {
        V = v;
    }
    public static int getRowsOfVMatrix() {
        return RowsOfVMatrix;
    }
    public static void setRowsOfVMatrix(int rowsOfVMatrix) {
        RowsOfVMatrix = rowsOfVMatrix;
    }
    public static int getColsOfVMatrix() {
        return ColsOfVMatrix;
    }
    public static void setColsOfVMatrix(int colsOfVMatrix) {
        ColsOfVMatrix = colsOfVMatrix;
    }
    public static int getROW_INCREASE() {
        return ROW_INCREASE;
    }
    public static void setROW_INCREASE(int rOW_INCREASE) {
        ROW_INCREASE = rOW_INCREASE;
    }
    public Matrix(){
        V = new double[Matrix.RowsOfVMatrix][Matrix.ColsOfVMatrix];
    }
    public Matrix(int rowsSize, int colSize){
        Matrix.RowsOfVMatrix = rowsSize;
        Matrix.ColsOfVMatrix = colSize;
        V = new double[Matrix.RowsOfVMatrix][Matrix.ColsOfVMatrix];
    }
    public Matrix(Matrix m){
        V = new double[Matrix.RowsOfVMatrix][Matrix.ColsOfVMatrix];
        for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.RowsOfVMatrix; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Matrix.ColsOfVMatrix; j++) {
                this.V[i][j] = m.V[i][j];
            }
        }       
    }
```

I Tried this code store `ArrayList` in `Matrix` using the following code

```
public static List<Matrix> readFromFileGetMatrixList(String filename)
                throws IOException {
            List<Matrix> ml = new ArrayList<Matrix>();
            Matrix m = null;
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String lineContent;
            int matrixNum = 0;
            while ((lineContent = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (lineContent.contains("#")) {
                    matrixNum++;
                }
            }
        matrixNum--;// the last one may be incomplete,so remove it from list
            br.close();
            fr.close();
            fr = new FileReader(filename);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            int matrixRow_index = 0;
            int matrixCount = 0;
            while ((lineContent = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (lineContent.contains("#")) {
                    if (matrixCount > 0) {
                        ml.add(m);
                        matrixRow_index = 0;
                    }
                    if (matrixCount == matrixNum)
                        break;
                    m = new Matrix();
                    continue;
                }
                if (lineContent.equals("")) {
                    matrixCount++;
                    continue;
                }
                String[] str = lineContent.split("\t");
                for (int j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
                    m.getV()[matrixRow_index][j] = Double.parseDouble(str[j]); //Null pointer Exception
     }
                matrixRow_index++;
            }
            return ml;
        }
```

This is my Text file sample

> 0 qid:1 1:1.000000 2:0.693147 3:0.166667 #docid = 285257 0 qid:1
>   1:1.000000 2:0.693147 3:0.166667 #docid = 285285 0 qid:1 1:1.000000
>   2:0.693147 3:0.166667 #docid = 285289 0 qid:1 1:1.000000 2:0.693147
>   3:0.166667 #docid = 285245

In above Code I am getting `ArrayBoundofIndexError`

Comment: can you point to the line by looking at the stacktrace?

Comment: In ReadFromfileGetMatrixList () method I am Getting error @ this line in Last For loop m.getV()[matrixRow_index][j] = Double.parseDouble(str[j])

Comment: `m.getV()` here `m` seems to be null

Comment: Not related to your question but: Is there a reason why you make ColsOfVMatrix  and RowsOfMatrix public? You have the public static getters to fetch their value...

Comment: How is c++ relevant to this question?

Comment: I am accessing the matrix in the Different package so I make it public @ Tom Jonkheere

Comment: @gajanan1 yes, but you can use those public static methods for that... Then you at least don't give them direct access to your variables... (actually you still do with your public static setters but still...)

Comment: @Tom Jonckheere Is There any Clue do you have for this Question

Comment: @gajanan1 I don't get the exception... the code reads the 3 lines from the textfile, and comes in the lineContent.contains("#") part. Then he hits the continue (3 times). After the third time he just exists the while loop...

Comment: did you Getting the console output in matrix format .. Can you Paste your Console output

Comment: @gajanan1 there is no output, the list with matricces (ml in your code) is empty... matrixcount == 0, so nothing is added and the continue statement causes it to never hit the matrixCount++...

Comment: In Blow loop am Creating matrix object and adding   ml.add(m)  value to ml